# AnimateWithDuration is functioning strangely

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

For some reason, if I just use the code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{

                             CGRect newDescriptFrame = [self.summaryTextField frame];
                             newDescriptFrame.size.height = (bkgndRect.size.height - kbSize.height) - ((newDescriptFrame.origin.y) + 10);
                             self.descriptionTextView.frame = newDescriptFrame;

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
```

It moves the `descriptionTextView` just fine, but if I add another animation block along with this.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         self.summaryLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                         self.summaryLabel.alpha = 1.0;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

The `descriptionTextView` reverts back to its original position before the animation when the 2nd block animates. Why does this happen? How do I fix it? If I move the alpha changes in the same block as the frame change. It does not animate the frame change at all.

Comment: This could be a layout constraint problem. Are you using a storyboard or xib? If so, try turning off auto layout (first tab on the left, the File Inspector), and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @rdelmar I have to use AutoLayout since I am using it in all the other views. Another strange thing that happens if I take the frame change out of the animation block it still will not change if I have the alpha animation blocks. If I comment out the alpha animation block, the frame gets changed....

Comment: Sometimes you see the is where it changes at first, but then when another view layout pass is made, things revert to their old positions. If you're using layout constrains, then you shouldn't be setting frames. You should make an outlet to whatever constraint you want to change, and animate the constraint instead.

Comment: @rdelmar Could you provide an example on what you mean by making an outlet to whatever constraints I want to change? Instead of frame change, should I use Transform instead? I narrowed it down. If I perform any action on the summaryLabel, even change the text, the frame will not change...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time right now to give you an example, but you don't use a transform. You animate the constant property of the constraint. You should check out the WWDC 2012 video, "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout", which discusses animation.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because only one animation can be executed at the same moment of time? Namely if you put together two animations in a single block of code, only the last one will be actually executed.